# How is this valid generic method in java?

Tags: java, generics, interface

```
class GenMethDemo {
// Determine if an object is in an array.

static <T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T> boolean isIn(T x, V[] y) {
     for(int i=0; i < y.length; i++)
         if(x.equals(y[i])) return true;
   }
}
```

how can Comparable interface be extended rather than being implemented being an Interface itself?

Comment: Although unrelated to the question about the type parameter, interfaces *do* extend other interfaces instead of implementing them. For example `interface Foo extends Comparable<Foo> {}`.

Answer (score 3):

The `Comparable` interface is not extended here.

`<T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T>` are generic type parameters with type bounds. It means that the `isIn` method has two generic type parameters - one of them is called `T` and must implement `Comparable<T>`, and the other is called `V`, and must be a sub-type of `T`.

BTW, your specific method doesn't require `V` and `T` to implement `Comparable`, since it doesn't call `compareTo`.

However, it would be required if you changed the code to:

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T> boolean isIn(T x, V[] y) {
     for(int i=0; i < y.length; i++)
         if(x.compareTo(y[i]) == 0) return true;
     return false;
}
```

Then you can call this method only with parameters that implement `Comparable`.

For example:

```
if (isIn ("str",new String[]{"a","b","c"})) {

}
```

Comment: Would it not make more sense to use rather a single type : `static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean isIn(T x, T[] y) {` ? Comparable instances are not necessarily designed to work with subclasses.

Comment: @davidxxx It probably would make more sense with a single type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of `extends` within `< ... >` is a little different from its 
normal meaning (like in `class FileInputStream extends InputStream`).

Quoted from the tutorial [Upper Bounded Wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html):

> To declare an upper-bounded wildcard, use the wildcard character (`?`),
>   followed by the `extends` keyword, followed by its *upper bound*.
>   Note that, in this context, `extends` is used in a general sense to mean either "extends" (as in classes) or "implements" (as in interfaces).